# TCP socket setting in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, tcp, nsstream

I find a method like `setReceiveBufferSize()` in Java on Objective C.
I use NSStream for TCP connection but there is no method of any kind of like that. If you know how to set a socket in IOS please comment for me!

Comment: I will assume you are talking about `NSInputStream` since you mentioned `setReceiveBufferSize()`. Maybe [read:maxLength:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsinputstream/1411544-read?language=objc) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @Bill I wanna set socket, not stream. Like timeout, linger,... I also think `read:maxLength:`is close but not working for me... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`setSockopt()` function in C is working!

You can set receive buffer size in IOS like this;

`setSockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REVBUF, &buf, sizeof(buf));`